# Website does not scale down for mobile screens

Tags: css, less, css-transitions

I am making a web for desktop, tablet and mobile screens. For this I am using css media queries. When I test my website on desktop browser and when I scale my web bowser down then it does change its layout when it reaches to max-width 740px as mentioned in css. But the problem is when I test this on my mobile then it does not change its layout to fit mobile screens.

I am using 12 columns layout system and using **[less css](http://lesscss.org/)**. Please help me why it does not change its layout on mobile phones to fit mobile screens.

Here is my css or less css to be precise

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
//overflow: hidden;
}

body {
min-width: 360px;
background-color: #ffffff;

#page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.right {
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}

// Extend column system (from defaults/layout.css)
.row {
    clear: both;

    > .container {
        max-width: 1024px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 2% 0 2%;

        .container {
            max-width: 100%;
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 0;

            &.one {
                width: 8%;
            }
            &.two {
                width: 16%;
            }
            &.three {
                width: 25%;
            }
            &.four {
                width: 33%;
            }
            &.five {
                width: 41%;
            }
            &.six {
                width: 50%;
            }
            &.seven {
                width: 58%;
            }
            &.eight {
                width: 66%;
            }
            &.nine {
                width: 75%;
            }
            &.ten {
                width: 83%;
            }
            &.eleven {
                width: 91%;
            }
            &.twelve {
                width: 100%;
            }

        }
    }
}

}



/*Collapse columns*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 740px) {

.column, .column.one, .column.two, .column.three, .column.four, .column.five, .column.six, .column.eight, .column.nine, .column.ten, .column.eleven, .column.twelve,
.column.close-right, .column.one.close-right, .column.two.close-right, .column.three.close-right, .column.four.close-right, .column.five.close-right, .column.six.close-right, .column.eight.close-right, .column.nine.close-right, .column.ten.close-right, .column.eleven.close-right, .column.twelve.close-right {
    //width: auto;
    //float: none;
    //clear: both;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.column.third {
    display: none;
}

.column.second {
    width: 77%;
}

.column.first {
    //min-width: 180px;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.allenpike.com/2010/choosing-a-viewport-for-ipad-sites/

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to the top of your HTML page:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

That should let the mobile browser know that the page you be rendered at the size of your device/browser, instead of faking the screen size of a desktop computer (and thus confusing your media queries).